# there any way to stop the execution of a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to stop the execution of a block ng-repeat when a condition is met, there is some way to go.

Something like that:

```
<div ng-reapeat="item in items">
   <div ng-if="item.age === 0">
      here I need to break the ng-repeat
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No you can not do this, filter items if you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom filter that break as soon as a condition is met :

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i] === 4) break;
      result.push(input[i]);
    }

    return result;
  };
});

app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data =   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="d in data | myFilter">
    {{d}}
  </div>
</body>
```